# MySQL Alter Column causes Error 1205 and error 2046

Tags: mysql, alter

I'm using MySQL Workbench and trying to alter a column name. The column is part of many foreign keys.

I'm thinking that's what's causing the error. I'm trying to rename `strCustomerCode` to `strCustomerCodeNEW`

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE `Check4It_MainDB`.`tbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFO` 
CHANGE COLUMN `strCustomerCode` `strCustomerCodeNEW` VARCHAR(255) 
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ;
```

Here is the error:

> ERROR 1025: Error on rename of './Check4It_MainDB/#sql-b6a_4a5' to './Check4It_MainDB/tbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFO' (errno: 150)

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `Check4It_MainDB`.`tbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFO` 
CHANGE COLUMN `strCustomerCode` `strCustomerCodeNEW` VARCHAR(255) 
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL
```

> ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow
>   ERROR 1046: No database selected

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFO` (
    `strCustomerCode` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL'
    `strPasscodeAdmin` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `strPasscodeClient` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `idMainReport_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lngProcedure_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `strHardDriveID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `lngInspector_01_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lngInspector_02_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lngShift_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lngUnit_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `dtmReportCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `dtmReportSubmitted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `bolCompleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `memReportComments` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `strTextMessage` varchar(160) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `bolTextMessageOn` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `bolTextSent` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `bolReportEmailSent` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `bolCompletionEmailSent` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `bolReportPostedToCloud` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `strComputerName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `strUserLogin` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `strUserVersionNUmber` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `bolImportedReport` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `bolTestReport` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    `strOSVersion` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `strWindowsVersion` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`idMainReport_ID`, `strCustomerCode`, `strPasscodeAdmin`, `strPasscodeClient`),

KEY `idMainTest_ID1` (`lngProcedure_ID`),
KEY `idProcedure_ID` (`idMainReport_ID`),
KEY `lngMemebrInfoID` (`lngInspector_01_ID`),
KEY `lngShift_ID` (`lngShift_ID`),
KEY `lngUnit_ID` (`lngUnit_ID`),
KEY `strHardDriveID` (`strHardDriveID`),
KEY `strPasscodeClient` (`strPasscodeClient`),
KEY `tbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFOstrPasscodeAdmin` (`strPasscodeAdmin`),
KEY `tblREF_InspectorInfotbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFO` (`lngInspector_01_ID`,`strCustomerCode`),
KEY `strPasscodeAdmin` (`strPasscodeAdmin`,`strCustomerCode`,`lngProcedure_ID`),
KEY `idMainReport_ID` (`idMainReport_ID`,`strPasscodeAdmin`,`strCustomerCode`,`strPasscodeClient`),
KEY `strCustomerCode` (`strCustomerCode`,`lngInspector_02_ID`),
KEY `lngShift_ID_2` (`lngShift_ID`,`strCustomerCode`),
KEY `strCustomerCode_2` (`strCustomerCode`,`lngUnit_ID`),

CONSTRAINT `FK_WithShiftID` FOREIGN KEY (`lngShift_ID`) REFERENCES `tblREF_ShiftID` (`idShift_ID`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: So I'm going to assume that the out of place `'` on the second line of your `create` statement is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says

> ERROR 1046: No database selected

This is because no database was selected. How is the sql server supposed to know what database to look for the table `Check4It_MainDB`?

To do this in the workbench, right-click a database and choose `Set As Default Schema`. This will now make any script that does not explicitly give a database to use your indicated database.

The better way is to add this to the top of all your scripts:

```
use MyDatabaseName;
```

Any code executed after that will use that database, unless again explicitly defined.

Comment: Well, I was able to run the ALTER on other tables that had no foreign keys. Only those with foreign keys had a problem.  I already had the default database set and used a new SQL Tab (Upper left menu icon) in MySQL. Maybe the issue was due to the way the FK was trying to be altered with the new column name and not having the explicit DB name. The way I fixed it was do do a dump of the whole DB (it's not very large), did a global replace in the script of the column name and reloaded it.  That fixed it.